# Pyside2 vs Pyside6

Tags: python, pyside2, pyside6

Подскажите, есть ли какое-то принципиальное различие между ними, с какого лучше начинать?
И если я правильно понял, то они обе бесплатны для коммерческого использования?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/porting_from2.html